# How To show Pop animation on deletion of message in chat?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have made a flutter chat app, using Firebase.

I am listening to the messages using a stream builder. Another feature of my chat app is, when the user long presses his chat message, the message gets deleted.

I want to show a pop animation of the deleted message because right now message gets deletes abruptly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a show dialog for this.

```
void _showDialog() {
    // flutter defined function
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // return object of type Dialog
        return AlertDialog(
          content: new Text("Are you sure you want to delete?"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
            FlatButton(
              child: new Text("Delete"),
              onPressed: () {
                // Your deleteMessage method!
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: new Text("Close"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

You can read more from the [official document](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html).

Comment: My question is not how to ask user to delete message , but how to show some type of Pop or destroyed Animation of that deleted message rather then abruptly deleting. Because Using a dialogue box or directly deleting is a same thing. Question focuses more on deleting animation.

Answer (score 0):

the thing that you need is animated widget i don't know what kind of animation you need or how you going to use it but the best way to make it is watch or read the animated widget from [flutter official doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations)